# How to print the correct number of digits contains in the double variable?

Tags: c++

The Expected Output is:

> The Value **123456789** contains **9** digits.

But the given output is:

> The Value **1.23457e+08** contains **332** digits

The Source:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main ()
{
  double number_1 = 123456789;
  double numberOfdigits = 1;
  double tmp = number_1;
    while (tmp /= 10)
      numberOfdigits ++;
        cout << "The Value " << number_1 << " contains " << numberOfdigits << " digits " << '\n';
}
```

Comment: `double` is a bad, bad, bad choice for such problems due to rounding issues. Be aware that even most simple 0.1 cannot be represented exactly in double as it is periodical in binary representation!

Comment: @RoQuOTriX and if **tmp** is even **int** the out put is The Value 1.23457e+08 contains 9 digits

Comment: Assume that all doubles have infinite digits, because they do. 4.2 for example has infinite digits, most of which are zeros. You cannot solve this problem with doubles in the general case because they store undetermined values instead of those zeros.

Comment: @RoQuOTriX Only partially correct. At some point you get numbers small enough not being representable in double any more, and these then can get rounded to 0.0. That's why Arnold gets output at all...

Comment: @RoQuOTriX that's not correct, if the divison results in a value smaller than 5e-324, it will be 0. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double-precision_floating-point_format

Comment: @mch and Anaconcagua, oh yes you are right. bad mistake, sorry

Comment: I consider `The Value 1.23457e+08 contains 332 digits` a good and probably correct response.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> The Expected Output is: The Value 123456789 contains 9 digits.
>
> ```
> while (tmp /= 10)
> ```

Either the end condition is wrong, or your expected output is wrong. The first 9 values of `tmp` are<sup>1</sup>:

```
123456789.
12345678.9
1234567.89
123456.789
12345.6789
1234.56789
123.456789
12.3456789
1.23456789
```

What do you expect the next value to be? Why do you expect it to be zero, which would end the loop? The next value will be 0.123456789, which is not zero and therefore does not end the loop.

If the number was represented with infinite precision, then the loop would continue indefinitely because dividing a number to smaller fractions never reaches zero mathematically. However, due to limited precision of floating point arithmetic it cannot represent arbitrarily small values, and the result will at some point round to zero<sup>1</sup>.

---

<sup>1</sup> Except for the value 123456789. the shown mathematically accurate value of `tmp` may not be exactly representable by the floating point format and thus the actually stored value may be something very close to, but not exactly the shown value.

Given that further operations are performed on the slightly inaccurate value, the error accumulates through the oprations and could in theory increase. In this case we divide the erroneus value, and therefore the previous error scales down as well, so it should not get out of hand in this case.

---

If you want to know the number of digits in an integer, then simplest solution is to not involve floating point in the first place.

Comment: Maybe worth to note that all the matter gets even worth, as all but very first number cannot be represented exactly in double, so we get something like 12345678.9 ± ε?

Comment: @Aconcagua I added something about the representation.

Answer (score 5):

Don't use Double unless you don't need to calculate and get the exact results.
In your case you can just use **int** or **const int** as you wish.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main ()
{
  int const number_1 = 123456789;
  double numberOfdigits = 1;
  int tmp = number_1;
    while (tmp /= 10)
    numberOfdigits ++;
    cout << "The Value " << number_1 << " contains " << numberOfdigits << " digits " << '\n';
}
```

Comment: The answer does not explain why `double` is a bad choice or why it doesn't work in the original OP. And `numberOfDigits` should also be integral.

Answer (score 2):

In your loop, you don't stop until `double` can't represent such a small number. You could stop when you go below 1

```
#include <iostream>
int main ()
{
  double number_1 = 123456789;
  int numberOfdigits = 1;
  double tmp = number_1;
  while ((tmp /= 10) > 1)
      numberOfdigits ++;

  std::cout << "The Value " << number_1 << " contains " << numberOfdigits << " digits " << '\n';
}
```

However there is a better way. Rather than repeatedly dividing by 10, you could [take a logarithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logarithm)

```
#include <cmath>
#include <iostream>
int main ()
{
  double number_1 = 123456789;
  int numberOfdigits = std::floor(std::log10(number_1)) + 1;
  std::cout << "The Value " << number_1 << " contains " << numberOfdigits << " digits " << '\n';
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The "number of digits of a float" is a questionable term. If it's really about floats you might use the log function.

```
 double x = 123456789.0;
 int magnitude =  log(x); // truncates 8.09.. to 8
 cout << x << " has " << magnitude+1 << " digits left of the decimal point." << endl;
```

If you want to get "The number of digits of 2.5 is 2" you are in trouble anyway...